# Dynamically load images into overlayed canvases and resize them

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have two canvases, which are overlaid. Now I want to load dynamically images into the canvases and adapt their size to the image size.

My problem now, is that after the canvases load the images and resize them self, they overlay all other html items below.

Here is the minimal example:

```js
loadimage.onclick = function(e) {
  //load image1
  var img1 = new Image();

  img1.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //resize canvas1
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };

  img1.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/250/0000FF/808080/";


  //load image2
  var img2 = new Image();

  img2.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //resize canvas1
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 75, 75);
  };

  img2.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/50/00FF00/808080/";
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 200px; height: 100px;">
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="100" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0; border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="100" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1; border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
</div>

<button id="loadimage" type="button">Load Content</button>
```

After pressing the "Load Content"
button, the button doesn 't move down.

I tried to change also the width and height properties of the "container"
div, but the behaviour did not change.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Why are you using canvases? Ordinary `img`/`picture` element should be sufficient.

Comment: In my original code I'm manipulating the images in the canvas further (drawing, resizing the images in the upper layers etc.)

Answer (score 0):

So, the code has many problems. If you are beginner, don't worry. That's normal. ☺

Firstly, **`<canvas>` is pair tag**. That means that you have to close it using `</canvas>`. The correct form is `<canvas someattribute="somevalue"></canvas>`. Inside the `<canvas>` tag is place for *alternative content* that will be used when the browser does not support the `<canvas>` tag (it is quite new).

Omitting the `</canvas>` broke the page.

HTML dictates what tags must be closed and what shouldn't and `<canvas>` is one of tags that **must** be closed. [The Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) could help you identify mistakes in the code. Note that it is quite pedantic.

The second problem is that you were using absolute positioning and the canvases, when resized, **overlaid the button**. Simply disable the positioning or use some more precise way of positioning. The third option is to resize the container div appropriately in the JS.

The container div had also set fixed size. By default, when the content is larger, **it overflows**.

You were probably trying to solve it using `z-index`. Setting z-indexes is usually quite tricky and I try to use it as the last resort. Both your `z-index` properties were not valid. **It is `z-index: NUMBER`**, not `z- index` or `z index`.

And the last bug I have found was that you were using `canvas1` (undefined variable) instead of `canvas` in the second function.

```js
loadimage.onclick = function(e) {
  //load image1
  var img1 = new Image();

  img1.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");

    //resize canvas1
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };

  img1.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/250/0000FF/808080/";


  //load image2
  var img2 = new Image();

  img2.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //resize canvas1
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };

  img2.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/50/00FF00/808080/";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
</div>

<button id="loadimage" type="button">Load Content</button>
```

Comment: Wait a moment, I'll add explanation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors, I fixed them in my question.
You answer example just displays the images side by side, but I overlaid the canvases, because I want to display the second image on top of the first one. Like a layer functionality in photoshop (or similiar image editing software).

Comment: And, when you want to draw multiple images, you can draw them both onto one canvas.

Comment: So when I want to later on edit the image on top, for example rotate, change alpha values, I always have to redraw the complete image?

Comment: @al3xst Yes that's an option. If you are working on graphics editor, it will be probably required. When you let the CSS and browser's rendering engine do the work for you, it will probably do not do anything different. If you will work with large images, downscale them once and render the downscaled version.